# Excel VBA Hyperlinks().Delete stripping cell formating

Tags: excel, vba

How does one stop the Delete method from deleting the cells formatting too.

When I use

```
rng.Hyperlinks(1).Delete
```

it deletes the cell formatting along with the cells conditional formatting.

Is this by design?

Comment: No idea, but you can use `rng.clearhyperlinks` if you're getting rid of all the hyperlinks and the formatting should persist.

Comment: @rory move your comment to Answer and I will accept it. I had no idea about that method. Much cleaner and simpler. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting rid of all the hyperlinks, you can use `rng.clearhyperlinks`  and the formatting should persist.

FWIW, although I don't know for sure, I suspect the issue is that adding a hyperlink applies the Hyperlink style to the cell and someone thought it would be a good idea to clear the formatting when the link was deleted. Just wasn't fully, or well, implemented!

Comment: Is `ClearHyperlinks` implemented in Excel 2003 ?

Comment: I don't recall, I'm afraid.